# Combining images but ending up with low quality

Tags: python, image

I've been trying, for some time now, to collage together various different, individually large images, so as to form a single, far greater, combined image, but for some reason, the actual product seems to be of lower quality, and far more pixelated, than the individual images I indended to combine. Does anyone have any idea on what is happening? (if this is of any use, the final image was meant to be a 100000 x 60000 pixel png)

I've programmed this in python, and the code is as follows:

```
import pyvips
import os

# Open the first piece of the image
piece0 = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(os.path.join("UpscaledImages", "piece_0.png"))

# Calculate the size of the original image
width, height = piece0.width, piece0.height
full_width = width * 8
full_height = height * 8

# Create a new image with the correct size
finishedImage = pyvips.Image.black(full_width, full_height)

# Paste each piece into the full image
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        print(f"done {i*8+j}")
        piece_filename = f"UpscaledImages/piece_{i*8+j}.png"
        piece = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(piece_filename)
        x = i * width
        y = j * height

        finishedImage = finishedImage.insert(piece, x, y)

finishedImage.write_to_file("finalImg.png")
```

I was expecting to combine the already existing images without any significant quality loss, but the images, when combined, appeared far more pixelated and of lower quality than the originals. I've tried using other libraries, such as CV2 to combine the images, but the result seems to always be the same.